# jquery performance issue, action registering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, action

I generate a page containing 100 textfields, each have the same action registered on it, but with different id and values:

```
<input type="textfield" id="tf1" value="tf1" onClick="textfieldclicked(this);" onChange="textfieldchanged(this);" onBlur="textfieldblur(this);" onFocus="textfieldfocus(this)"


<input type="textfield" id="tf2" value="tf2" onClick="textfieldclicked(this);" onChange="textfieldchanged(this);" onBlur="textfieldblur(this);" onFocus="textfieldfocus(this)"

..

<input type="textfield" id="tf00" value="tf100" onClick="textfieldclicked(this);" onChange="textfieldchanged(this);" onBlur="textfieldblur(this);" onFocus="textfieldfocus(this)"
```

I generate the html content using servlet, send to browser using ajax set them to the page using jquery. I have network performance problems, so have to minimize the content sent from servlet. What would be the best solution to minimize the content?

1-using strig compression on servlet side(java) and string decompress on clientjavascript)?, because we have many common templates, the compression can provide up to 90% compress ratio.

2-assinging a class to each textfield, then registering to them using jquery

```
$('.textfieldclass').onBlur(..)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give all the inputs a common class and register events in jQuery as shown :-

```
$('.someclass').on('click change blur focus',function(){
  // ....
});
```

Comment: thanks, I learned something new. You can define multiple events